# Parse xml & delete a node in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I tried to parse an XML & delete a node "displayTextFlow" from the XML. Below is my code:

```
$filePath = file_get_contents('sample.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($filePath);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $key => $element) {
    if ($key == 'displayTextFlow') {
        unset($iterator[$key]);
    }
}
$finalXML = $xml->asXML();
print_r($finalXML);
exit;
```

In my sample XML, I'm not sure about the exact place for the tag "displayTextFlow". It may come in any other place. So I need to write a code to parse the XML & delete the tag "displayTextFlow" in all the places
Note: I need to do it only using SimpleXMLIterator.

Please check the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document savedInEditor="false">
<pages numIncludedPages="2">
    <item includeInOutputComputed="true">
        <frames>
            <item id="2555D134-0F82-49A8-B3CD-4536DB607AE5" name="New Frame">
                sample text
            </item>
            <item id="C15D2F81-3925-4E3E-B1F4-3F6729CAF8AD" name="New Frame 1">
                sample text
            </item>
            <item id="AD0216C3-CD41-4994-B8AC-9E2DACF7439E" name="New Frame 2">
                <displayTextFlow>
                    <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008" />
                </displayTextFlow>
                <textFlow>
                    <TextFlow>
                        <span>Sampe span​</span>
                    </TextFlow>
                </textFlow>
            </item>
            <item id="0DBBAAB8-A572-49BF-8E77-BDAC88219DC7" name="New Frame 3">
                <displayTextFlow>
                    <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008" />
                </displayTextFlow>
                <textFlow>
                    <TextFlow>
                        <span>Sampe span​ frame 3</span>
                    </TextFlow>
                </textFlow>
            </item>
            <item id="4B392B37-3B2C-443A-A6B6-4219184D848D" name="New Frame 4">
                <displayTextFlow>
                    <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008" />
                </displayTextFlow>
                <textFlow>
                    <TextFlow>
                        <span>Sampe span​ frame 4</span>
                    </TextFlow>
                </textFlow>
            </item>
            <item id="E82B3F8D-02F9-45E5-8955-4F161C0DCAF4" name="New Frame 5">
                <displayTextFlow>
                    <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
                        <span>needs to be removed</span>
                    </TextFlow>
                </displayTextFlow>
                <textFlow>
                    <TextFlow>
                        <span>needs to be removed</span>
                    </TextFlow>
                </textFlow>
            </item>
        </frames>
        <sectionOptions includeInOutput="true" newSection="true" pageStart="1"/>
    </item>
</pages>
<item id="E82B3F8D-02F9-45E5-8955-4F161C0DCAF4" name="sample 1">
    <displayTextFlow>
        <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
            <span>needs to be removed</span>
        </TextFlow>
    </displayTextFlow>
    <textFlow>
        <TextFlow>
            <span>needs to be removed</span>
        </TextFlow>
    </textFlow>
</item>
<item id="E82B3F8D-02F9-45E5-8955-4F161C0DCAF4" name="sample 2">
    <displayTextFlow>
        <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
            <span>needs to be removed</span>
        </TextFlow>
    </displayTextFlow>
    <textFlow>
        <TextFlow>
            <span>needs to be removed</span>
        </TextFlow>
    </textFlow>
</item>
</document>
```

Comment: You should mention what the problem is.

Comment: I couldn't delete the tag "displayTextFlow" from the xml.

Comment: You can use xpath to find tags. example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501216/getting-tag-names-from-xml-using-xpath

Comment: In my case, the xml doesn't have a proper structure. So it'll be difficult to use xpath.

Comment: The sample xml in your question is well formed; isn't the actual xml well formed too?

Comment: Did you by chance omit a namespace definition on the `document` element?

Comment: @JackFleeting It is one of the sample XML files. Similarly, I'll get the XML in the different structure